# Infinite-like space for Conway&#39;s Game of Life in html/js with canvas

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I want to create a CellularAutomation(Life Game) using HTML/js, and I've already realized one with canvas and js.

But I have some trouble in the margin zone. In my case, a slider slid to the edge and turns out a cube(grave OR still live pattern). Maybe I should, for example, create an array[100][100] and show array[90][90] in the middle, and that I am afraid that the cube(grave...) could influence other cells(I mean alive cell like another slider) which slid by it.

But space(canvas) for all cells is finite. I remember I've visited a web site(I forgot the URL -_-!) that simulates LifeGame and I can use mouse scroll to zoom in or out. It gives me a feeling that it's infinite and I can zoom out to make those cells looks very small. The most important is that it has no edge problem in my case at all.

I'm not sure that the web is or is not using canvas, maybe it uses SVG.

So, how to create an infinite or infinite-like space for those cells.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: that's the URL that i forgot, thank ~

Comment: Questions can't depend on links to live sites here. Your question needs to contain all code required to find an answer in the form of a *minimal* complete example.